# Using custom taxonomy when registering a new custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm creating my own custom post type and here is the code for this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_gallery_post_type' );
function create_gallery_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'gallery',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Galleries' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Gallery' )
      ),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    )
  );
}
```

I have another custom post type that has it's own custom category taxonomy and that is called `portfolio-category'. I'd like to use the same taxonomy for this post type since they would be the same values and I only have to enter them in one place.

I tried to make it say:

```
'taxonomies' => array('portfolio-category')
```

This didn't show me the categories link under my Gallery post type though. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you assign a taxonomy to a post type and not a post type to a taxonomy. Check your taxonomy code.

Comment: @gdaniel I already registered the other taxonomy. I was thinking that since it's registered I can just tell the post type to use that taxonomy.

Comment: @gdaniel it works both ways, shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work in principle. Note that `taxonomies` argument needs *existing* taxonomy, that is one that is already registered at the time you are registering CPT.

If the timing is problematic to get right during registration, you could also use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_taxonomy_for_object_type/) to create association between the two separately from registration process.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe that is my issue. I'm declaring this custom post type in my functions.php file within my child theme. The other custom taxonomy is being registered from within my main theme so maybe the functions.php is executing before the other taxonomy is created. I'm currently using the `init` hook to create this taxonomy like this `add_action( 'init', 'create_gallery_post_type' );`. Is there a different hook to use to create this after the files in my main theme are loaded?

Comment: I actually changed the hook to `wp_loaded` and then changed my taxonomy to the `portfolio-category` and it now loads succcessfully. Is the `wp_loaded` hook ok to use?

Comment: @user1048676 I would say just use `init` for everything and specify priorities to control order. `wp_loaded` is a fine hook, but it is rarely used and so a little unconventional.

Comment: How can I specify priorities? I've never used that before.

Comment: @user1048676 [`add_action()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_action/) accepts priority as an argument, it's very common/necessary way to use it :)

Comment: Thanks I set the priority to 100 and that also worked when I switched the action back to `init`. Thanks for the help.